# how to only allow text in parsely.js validation

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

I am using the nifty [parsley js](http://parsleyjs.org/) As you can see in [the documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html)
there is only `data-parsley-type="alphanum"` which allows numbers and letters. I am trying to create fields that ONLY allow letters.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 19):

You could use a pattern:

```
data-parsley-pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use such input validator, in order to obtain an only letter field.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" required data-parsley-pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" placeholder="Type something" />
```